# slideDown doesn't work on responsive toggle with flex display

Tags: jquery, html, css

So here is my JSFiddle to setup the problem space https://jsfiddle.net/67nx5paw/11/

Firstly, I have a navbar which collapses to use a toggle icon to display the menu. I tried using the `slideDown` and `slideToggle` functions, however they do not do anything. The jQuery I am using is as follows (and I even used `console.log` to check if it is being called and it is.

```
$(function() {
    $('#toggle').on('click', function(e) {
        console.log('Clicked');
        $('#content').slideToggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

As seen in the fiddle link, I use `display: flex` on the nav elements and then call `display: none` to hide them in the respective views. Is the toggle not working because of the `flex` diplay value?

Comment: `!important` is the issue. Updated Jsfiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/xfbjfw9a/](https://jsfiddle.net/xfbjfw9a/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your fiddle, and in your css, there is a `css` rule with `!important`.

```
nav.nav .nav-content {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Remove the `!important`, and it will work.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/67nx5paw/21/)

Update:

If you use an `!important`, it will override the inline `style` set by javascript. Normally, with `slideDown()`, jQuery add an inline style which will set the display property of the element where you want to `slideDown()` to block. Therefore, with `!important`, the browser see that the css rule has an high priority.

Comment: Firstly, why is the `!important` the issue? And secondly, is there a way I can get the menu to now show in `flex` underneath the navbar?

Comment: Important is a matter, because, it override the style set by javascript.

Comment: I noticed that when I use the toggle, after resizing sometimes the nav elements disappear - how can I fix this?

Comment: You can play with @media to fix this

Comment: Could you point me to a way in which I can achieve this? That statement is relatively arbitrary

Comment: Check your code, there is two `!important` into it. Maybe it is the cause of the bug

Comment: I removed both the `!important` values, so its not that